# Which has better performance?Accesing global variable directly from a function or assigning it to another variable?

Tags: javascript

Here I have two examples of accessing global variables;
basic example of my global variable

```
globalVar:any={
 a:5,
 b:3,
 c:4
}
```

Ex.1

```
function accesVar(){
 return this.globalVar.a*=2
}
```

Ex.2

```
 function accesVar(){
    let _var=this.globalVar.a;
    return _var*=2
    }
```

In this example global variable doesnt seem a good practise and I dont use them when I dont need to share  variables with more than one function.Considering in general and real world(much bigger data),which would be best approach and has better performance?

Comment: With all the different optimizations that engines do, I think the only answer is "it depends".

Comment: That said, your demo is one where the value is used only once, I would think *conceptually* that the extra variable assignment would mean extra work. But I would also guess that it would be optimized away.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt this would ever be the bottleneck in any large-scale application. If you are using a global at all, I don't think Ex.2 is better than Ex.1. I'd stick with Ex.1 because it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Both have different importance. 
Example one is direct use of globle variable. Saves you extra declaration.
Example two is useful when we need to use the global value many times inside the function.

Comment: My question is without any iteration only at once